# Custom Dimension doesn't show up in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have the following custom dimension parameter that I'm sending on page view:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', { 'environment': 'DEV' });
```

(DEV changes depending on the website environment)

I logged into `Google Analytics => Admin => Custom Definitions/Custom Dimensions`, then `"New Custom Dimension`" and added `"environment"`, `Scope = Hit.`

I created a custom report that included Pageviews as the Metric and `"environment"` as the Dimension and I don't see any information for the custom dimension I added.  The js has been in there for several weeks (throughout our development cycle) so I would expect to see some information.

Am I missing a step somewhere?

*Bear with me if I'm calling something by the wrong name, I'm relatively new to Google Analytics.*

Thanks

JH

Comment: Is there any chance they had to be set up in Analytics first before the javascript will start tracking the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom dimensions are set by number, what you have named them in the GA interface shouldn't appear in the code. So for your example you'd have

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimensionX':  'DEV'
});
```

where X is the number of the dimension you wish to set.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I think I was confusing the way it was set in the old analytics library with the new one.